# sysex from AudioKit's receivedMIDISystemCommand

Tags: swift, midi, audiokit, sysex

I am very new to Swift and struggling so please go easy.  I am building a macOS project using Swift 4 in XCode 10.1

I am receiving a sysex message from a device using the following code which I got from the MIDIUtility example project supplied with AudioKit:

```
func receivedMIDISystemCommand(_ data: [MIDIByte]) {
    if let command = AKMIDISystemCommand(rawValue: data[0]) {
        var newString = "MIDI System Command: \(command) \n"
        var hexArray = [UInt8]()
        for bit in data {
            hexArray.append(bit)    //this requires 'public typealias MIDIByte = UInt8'
            newString.append(String("\(bit) "))
        }
        updateText("\(newString) \n")
        updateData(hexArray)
    }
    updateText("received \(data.count) bytes of data \n\n")
}
```

The sysex I am receiving is very different than what I get when using SysEx Librarian or MIDI Monitor to receive the same sysEx.  Both of these apps receive 6 packets of 32,110,110,110,110, and 110 bytes.  This is what I expect to get from my MIDI device.  My code gets 6 packets of 520,1300,20,1538,1294 and 1544 bytes.  It looks like the data I want is in these packets, but it is spit up by a bunch of 0's.

[data as received in MIDI Monitor or SysEx Librarian:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn3Og.png)
[some of the data as received by my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJdXE.jpg)

Why is my code receiving so much extra data?  Is there a way to filter out the unwanted data or will I need to figure out how to use something other that AudioKit for my project?

Comment: Duplicate of [Receiving Sysex messages with audiokit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52676218/receiving-sysex-messages-with-audiokit).

Comment: Probable duplicate: [Audiokit seems to receive only the first three numbers of sysex MIDI messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46680560/audiokit-seems-to-receive-only-the-first-three-numbers-of-sysex-midi-messages).

Comment: Check that you have the latest AK version, then [report a bug](https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/issues).

Comment: those 2 other posts never got a helpful answer, that is why I asked it again.  I considered reporting this as a bug, but wasn't sure if it was a bug or that there was something I was doing wrong.

Comment: Definitely seems like a bug, thanks for also raising an issue on Github.